# Postgres default value is the difference of two records

Tags: sql, postgresql, expression, default

I have a postgres table with columns: id, text, timestamp, diff
id is auto generated, text is inserted, timestamp is default and diff should be the difference of the current record's timestamp and the previous record's timestamp (prev by id) if the previous is the same day as the actual, if not, it should be 0. So all columns are auto generated when text is inserted.
Do you know any way to make this diff default through an expression or etc? I am newby to sql.

Thank you.

Comment: `DEFAULT` would be no use here, because it cannot contain subquery. You could fill the value with `ON INSERT` trigger.

Comment: A default expression cannot access other rows. You'd have to write a trigger for that. But why generating ans persisting that value? It can be calculated any time later. Persisting it bears the risk of inconsistencies. In general values that can be calculated from other persistent one shouldn't be persistent unless one has a very good reason and takes extra care to avoid inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you could use a trigger:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9769cb9f9658692c08248037a71fa400)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    id int,
    ts timestamp DEFAULT now(),                                     -- 1
    diff float                                                      -- 2
);

CREATE FUNCTION set_ts_diff() RETURNS trigger AS $$
    DECLARE
        _last_ts timestamp;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ts), NEW.ts) FROM tbl INTO _last_ts;    -- 3

        IF (NEW.ts::date = _last_ts::date) THEN                     -- 4
            NEW.diff := EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NEW.ts - _last_ts);      -- 5
        ELSE
            NEW.diff := 0;
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_set_ts_diff BEFORE INSERT ON tbl                  -- 6
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_ts_diff();
```

1. Create your table. `ts` gets current timestamp (`now()`) as default.
2. `diff` would be used as difference in seconds. Because two inserts could be done in one single second a `float` type helps. Another way could be the type `interval` which is the default type for timestamp subtractions (see point 5)
3. A trigger needs a trigger function to know what to do after an event was triggered. In this function we get the last `ts` stored in the `tbl` before. If no row exist, the current `ts` is taken (`NEW` is the current row to be inserted) with help of `COALESCE`
4. Then check if the last and the current `ts` have the same date (checked by casting both timestamps into `date`).
5. If so, calculate the difference which results in a type `interval`. To get the seconds from an `interval` use `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...)`.
6. Create the trigger: Before persisting the new row (`ON BEFORE INSERT`) execute the trigger function an set the `NEW.diff` column.

---

**Notice:**

You should barely persist data that can be calculated later. The difference between two timestamps can be calculated with the help of the [`LAG` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), which takes the value of the previous row to the current one ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d73c5a6794ef96ff6ad7d076428a68d1)):

```
SELECT
    ts,
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts - lag(ts) OVER (ORDER BY ts)) as diff
FROM
    tbl;
```

The disadvantage of hard storing the difference can be seen if you have to delete one row. The diff of the next one now has a wrong value because its reference is missing. Your data might become inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a `VIEW`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_tbl AS
SELECT id,
       txt,
       tstamp,
       coalesce (  extract ( epoch FROM tstamp - LAG(tstamp)
        OVER(PARTITION BY date_trunc('day',tstamp) ORDER BY id)),0)
 FROM tbl;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=97de6d921eaf1dde5038725b660ab0da)